# laravel: Route [dashboard] not defined

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

when admin login then he redirects to dashboard page but by clicking on its main button(like home button) it shows error, i added this code: `<a href="{{route('dashboard')}}">` in it but it says:

> Route [dashboard] not defined

this is my route:

```
  Route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
```

any solution to resolve this issue

Answer (score 5):

Give the name to Route.

```
Route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard);
```

or

```
Route::get('/admin/dashboard',[
            'uses' => 'AdminController@dashboard',
            'as' => 'dashboard']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route):

> **route()**
>
> The route function generates a URL for the given named route:
>
> $url = route('routeName');

as we see, it generates a URL for the given *named* *route*, so you have to provide a name for your route like the following from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) too:

> **Named Routes**
>
> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or
>   redirects for specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by
>   chaining the name method onto the route definition:
>
> Route::get('user/profile', function () {
>       // })->name('profile');
>
> You may also specify route names for controller actions:
>
> Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->name('profile');

So add a name to your route:

```
Route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

Hope it helps